# HttpClient.SendAsync using the thread-pool instead of async IO?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, dotnet-httpclient

So I've been digging up on the implementation of `HttpClient.SendAsync` via Reflector. What I intentionally wanted to find out was the flow of execution of these methods, and to determine which API gets called to execute the asynchronous IO work.

After exploring the various classes inside `HttpClient`, I saw that internally it uses `HttpClientHandler` which derives from `HttpMessageHandler` and implements its `SendAsync` method.

This is the implementation of `HttpClientHandler.SendAsync`:

```
protected internal override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (request == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("request", SR.net_http_handler_norequest);
    }

    this.CheckDisposed();
    this.SetOperationStarted();

    TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage> source = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();

    RequestState state = new RequestState 
    {
        tcs = source,
        cancellationToken = cancellationToken,
        requestMessage = request
    };

    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request2 = this.CreateAndPrepareWebRequest(request);
        state.webRequest = request2;
        cancellationToken.Register(onCancel, request2);

        if (ExecutionContext.IsFlowSuppressed())
        {
            IWebProxy proxy = null;

            if (this.useProxy)
            {
                proxy = this.proxy ?? WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
            }
            if ((this.UseDefaultCredentials || (this.Credentials != null)) || ((proxy != null) && (proxy.Credentials != null)))
            {
                this.SafeCaptureIdenity(state);
            }
        }

        Task.Factory.StartNew(this.startRequest, state);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        this.HandleAsyncException(state, exception);
    }
    return source.Task;
}
```

What I found weird is that the above uses `Task.Factory.StartNew` to execute the request while generating a `TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>` and returning the `Task` created by it.

Why do I find this weird? well, we go on alot about how I/O bound async operations have no need for extra threads behind the scenes, and how its all about overlapped IO.

Why is this using `Task.Factory.StartNew` to fire an async I/O operation? this means that `SendAsync` isn't only using pure async control flow to execute this method, but spinning a ThreadPool thread *"behind our back"* to execute its work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`this.startRequest` is a delegate that points to `StartRequest` which in turn uses `HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse` to start async IO. `HttpClient` is using async IO under the covers, just wrapped in a thread-pool Task.

That said, note the following [comment in `SendAsync`](https://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/NuGet/Project/HttpClient/0.5.0/Release/.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0/Microsoft.Net.Http/Microsoft.Net.Http/System/Net/Http/HttpClientHandler.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.Net.Http)

```
// BeginGetResponse/BeginGetRequestStream have a lot of setup work to do before becoming async
// (proxy, dns, connection pooling, etc).  Run these on a separate thread.
// Do not provide a cancellation token; if this helper task could be canceled before starting then 
// nobody would complete the tcs.
Task.Factory.StartNew(startRequest, state);
```

[This works around a well-known problem with HttpWebRequest: Some of its processing stages are synchronous.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624336/httpwebrequest-dns-resolution-in-advance) That is a flaw in that API. `HttpClient` is avoiding blocking by moving that DNS work to the thread-pool.

Is that good or bad? It is good because it makes `HttpClient` non-blocking and suitable for use in a UI. It is bad because we are now using a thread for long-running blocking work although we expected to not use threads at all. This reduces the benefits of using async IO.

Actually, this is a nice example of mixing sync and async IO. There is nothing inherently wrong with using both. `HttpClient` and `HttpWebRequest` are using async IO for long-running blocking work (the HTTP request). They are using threads for short-running work (DNS, ...). That's not a bad pattern in general. We are avoiding *most* blocking and we only have to make a small part of the code async. A typical 80-20 trade-off. It is not good to find such things in the BCL (a library) but in application level code that can be a very smart trade-off.

It seems it would have been preferable to fix `HttpWebRequest`. Maybe that is not possible for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Holy crap! Thanks. I was looking at http://sourceof.net and looking for that method implementation and it doesn't show any, only method signatures. That is indeed a shame! I wonder if anyone from MSFT can comment on that.

Comment: It seems a pretty small implementation details but this is rather big deal, isn't it? if im using `HttpClient.XXXAsync` methods to query many requests all-together, im not expecting each of them to internally use a ThreadPool thread. This isn't documented anywhere.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yes, I'm disappointed. This is below the usual quality standards that we are used to when using the BCL.

Comment: That said, don't fear the thread. Synchronous IO isn't that harmful and there is an irrational fear of it going on right now. It wouldn't really cause any damage to even have 100s of threads dedicated to DNS resolution. The main problem with that is the 1MB of stack size per thread. That's mostly it.

Comment: The 1MB of stack is allocated anyway when the ThreadPool initializes, doesn't it? Assuming it isn't out the default allocated number of threads.

Comment: 1MB per thread. The memory usage depends on how many threads are spawned. If DNS is really quick, like it is most of the time, a few threads can process all of the load.

Comment: It isn't only 1MB stack, its the Thread Local Storage, Thread Environment Block, Kernel mode Stack, etc.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov true, yet that 1MB is most of it. I just started 100k threads on my machine as a test using testlimits.exe. Threads are really not that big of a deal. 100k threads ought to be enough for anybody! :)

Comment: @usr Synchronous IO can be harmful in async code if the sync calls block for long. It can cause the task system to stall as it is a cooperative system. It does have some recovery logic that if stalls are for too long, a new thread-pool thread will start processing tasks, which will help hide the problem. Too many threads have negative scaling when CPU bound. In some extreme situations, you can become context-switching bound, showing low throughput and low CPU usage.

Comment: @Bengie this problem exists but it does not relate to async IO in any way. That's just classic thread pool exhaustion (which must be strictly avoided as you say). Whether to use sync or async IO is a cost-benefit tradeoff (in code path not on the UI thread). The main cost for async is dev time. There's no strict rule to always use either of them.