# Can HttpClient SendAsync not block GUI thread?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

The Windows Forms GUI thread keeps stalling for a second now and then during async `HttpClient SendAsync`. Except for that, everything works fine (I get data).  I want to do frequent and hopefully parallel requests to different servers to update the screen frequently. I am trying to launch multiple requests that post the responses for processing by the GUI thread later. The code below is a simplification of my code.
I've checked the time before and after `SendAsync` and see it is sometimes up to 2 seconds while the GUI window is frozen (can't be moved, scrolled, etc) and the polling timer is inactive (counter never incremented).

Using async `Task DoWork` did not help.

```
class Worker
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    bool busy = false;
    string data = "";
    //public async Task DoWork()
    public async void DoWork()
    {
        if ( busy ) return;
        busy = true;
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, requestUrl);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync( request );
        data = ... from response ...
        busy = false;
    }
}
int counter;
private void Update(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ++counter;
    foreach ( Worker worker in workers )
        worker.DoWork();
}
...
List<Worker> workers = ...
var poll = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
poll.Tick += Update;
poll.Interval = 250;
poll.Enabled = true;
...
```

Comment: Try sharing the client (declare it static), HttpClient is a heavy object and the proper way to use it is to reuse it.

Comment: Can 1 HttpClient be used for multiple simultaneous requests to multiple servers?
I was using 1 per server.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24983635/httpclient-sendasync-using-the-thread-pool-instead-of-async-io
mentions that SendAsync is not completely async, and uses a threadpool internally; Could the threadpoll be too small?

Comment: How have you determined that `GetAsync` is the issue?

Comment: Issue is not with SendAsync but with GUI updating being very slow

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows.Forms you may consider `BackgroundWorker`

Comment: Thanks. BackgroundWorker allowed separating the HttpClient work from the UI - and it became clear the UI was the bottleneck. My measurement method was faulty.

Answer (score 0):

`SendAsync` is sufficiently asynchronous (even if it uses threads internally).
Updating UI itself is really slow and the cause of UI freezing.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22986661)

Comment: I was trying to respond to my own question; The problem was not with SendAsync, but with slow updates to DataGridView. By putting them on different threads (BackgroundWorker) made that clear.